# How to delete Google sheet rows if two checkboxes o the row are true

Tags: checkbox, delete-row

i have a Google spreadsheet that we use to support our helpdesk

I'm trying to make a macro, on event, so that when two checkboxes in the row (column A and column H) are both true, the row is deleted.
I'm trying to figure how to do but with no sucess.
Anyone can help?
Thanks a lot

I tried some scripts available on web, to delete a single row on checkbox state, but i can't make them work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In my sheet i have two checboxes in column A and H. Starting from row 4, i would need that when BOTH checkboxes are TRUE, the row where the checkboxes are true is deleted. I thought to follow function deleteRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('SUPPORTO TECNICO');
  var r = s.getRange('A:A');
  var v = r.getValues();
  var k = s.getRange('H:H');
  var z = k.getValues();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if (v[0,i] =='true' && z[0,i]=='true')
      s.deleteRow(i+1);
};